# how can recognize Timer's callback (Timer Is In Master Page) In both Master & Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, master-pages

my pages are base on master and content pages in asp.net with c#.
i have a timer in master page like below :

```
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="10000" Enabled="False">
                            </asp:Timer>
                            <div id="SiteStatistics">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_Title" runat="server" Text="Download Count :" ToolTip="Download Count :"
                                    CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Count() %>" CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Title" runat="server" Text="Ur Download Count :"
                                    ToolTip="Your Download Count From The Begining Of Registration UpTo Now" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Count_By_UserID() %>"
                                    CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today_Title" runat="server" Text="Ur Download Count-Today :"
                                    ToolTip="Your Download Count-Today" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Count_By_UserID_Today" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Count_By_UserID_Today() %>"
                                    CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Title" runat="server" Text="Ur Download Size :"
                                    ToolTip="Your Download Size From The Begining Of Registration UpTo Now" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Size_By_UserID() %>"
                                    CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today_Title" runat="server" Text="Ur Download Size-Today :"
                                    ToolTip="Your Download Size-Today" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Size_By_UserID_Today() %>"
                                    CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today_Remain_Title" runat="server" Text="Ur Remain Download Size-Today :"
                                    ToolTip="Your Remain Download Size-Today" CssClass="lblTitleInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDownload_Size_By_UserID_Today_Remain" runat="server" Text="<%# Download_Size_By_UserID_Today_Remain() %>"
                                    CssClass="lblCountInStatistics"></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this timer ticks every 10 seconds and causes callbacks -> first page_load of content page and last page_load of master page fire every 10 seconds because of that timer!
how can i recognize that **timer'callback** in both master and content pages and prevent running codes again and again because of callback?

thanks in advance

Comment: Postbacks always trigger `Page_Load` of master **and** contentpage, you should handle the [Timer's Tick-Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.tick.aspx).

Comment: Or are you looking for the Page.IsCallback property?

Comment: What code are you running on every postback? Maybe you should surround it with a `!Page.IsPostback()`-check.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thanks 4 comment / but tick event can not help me for recognize timer's callback in both master and content page_load / besides timer's tick is in master page, so there is no such event for content page / i want to use an if in content page_load for pervent running content page_load codes when timer ticks ....

Comment: this is necessary for to recognize only timer's callback - not all callbacks / i think Page.IsCallback is ok / but in some callbacks i want page_load codes /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Remove the timer. It seems you don't actually want it/need it.
2. on Page_Load of both, Master and Page, enclose your code inside a `if(!IsPostBack){//code}`
3. On Page_Load check `Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]` and see if it contains `Timer1`

Comment: i was looking for option #3 -> that is exactly what i want ... thanks lcarus! i test it and it works.