# Multiples UpdatePanels with different Timers intervals

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have two UpdatePanels and two Timers to update them, the Timers' interval are different. The first UpdatePanel generates an asp:table rows dynamically from a query, the second one does the same from another query.

In the Page_Load event I do everything (Query the DB, fill the Table) then in the Page_PreRender event I use the ViewState to save some info I need to use after the page is loaded for that specific panel, and in the Timer_OnTick I do nothing actually.

My first panel works perfect, now, I need to do the same thing for the second Panel, but I'm worried about the concurrency of those panels since the update occurs in different intervals of time. That's one thing, the other one is how to update the specific panel according to the Timer since I have all the code in the Page_Load event.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Page_Load` check `Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"]` and see if it contains `Timer1` , `Timer2`, etc.

[Here's a link to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900874/how-can-recognize-timers-callback-timer-is-in-master-page-in-both-master-co)

Comment: Hi @Icarus, and what if the second timer event fires before the first one finish? since the intervals are not the same, it could happen right?

Comment: @Somebody: yes, I believe it could happen. The best way to know is testing and only you can do that. Give it a try :)

Comment: yeap, there is a conflit when the times are the same, any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Somebody no, there's no way to avoid it unless you synchronize the postbacks on the client side via javascript but you'll end up with a very very messy code. In general I don't like the approach you are using. I'd rather implement ajax calls to web methods to update the sections I want. The problem with update panels is that they do full postbacks and carry all the viewstate with them. I don't use them, they are inefficient and have these kind of problems you have.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Icarus, I found this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/57035/Simultanious-Async-Requests-Using-Multiple-Update that basically cancel a new request if another one is already in progress, I gonna try to make that work.

Comment: No way, it doesn't work, I will have to update both of them at the same time.

Comment: I had that feeling :) you can't rollback a request once is issued. You CAN do it, but not the way you had planned it. The way to go is Ajax with jQuery + web/page methods.

Comment: It sounds complicated, do you have any sample or link where I can look at?

Comment: It's not complicated at all. Dave Ward has a bunch of very good examples. Start with this one: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Thank so much for your help @Icarus, I will start from there.